# How to merge arrays based on parent loop in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a dataset of patients , room and payment method (which is an array of objects). Those 3 arrays looks like this:

```php
$rooms = [
   (object) [
      'roomCode' => 1,
      'roomName' => 'Room 1'
   ],
   (object) [
      'roomCode' => 2,
      'roomName' => 'Room 2'
   ],
   (object) [
      'roomCode' => 3,
      'roomName' => 'Room 3'
   ],
];

$paymentMethods = [
   (object) [
      'paymentCode' => 1,
      'paymentName' => 'Payment 1'
   ],
   (object) [
      'paymentCode' => 2,
      'paymentName' => 'Payment 2'
   ],
   (object) [
      'paymentCode' => 3,
      'paymentName' => 'Payment 3'
   ],
];

$patients = [
   (object) [
      'fullName' => 'Patient A',
      'roomCode' => 1,
      'paymentCode' => 1
   ],
   (object) [
      'fullName' => 'Patient B',
      'roomCode' => 1,
      'paymentCode' => 1
   ],
   (object) [
      'fullName' => 'Patient C',
      'roomCode' => 2,
      'paymentCode' => 1
   ],
   (object) [
      'fullName' => 'Patient D',
      'roomCode' => 1,
      'paymentCode' => 3
   ],
   (object) [
      'fullName' => 'Patient E',
      'roomCode' => 3,
      'paymentCode' => 3
   ],
];
```

What I'm expecting to achieve is to merge the patient array to room and payment method array to get their respective names based on the parent loop.

The expected array will kind of looks like this:

```php
$mergedArray = [
   [
      'Room 1' => [
          'Payment 1' => [
             0 => ['fullName' => 'Patient A'],
             1 => ['fullName' => 'Patient B']
          ],
          'Payment 2' => [],
          'Payment 3' => [
             0 => ['fullName' => 'Patient D'],
          ]
      ],
      'Room 2' => [
          'Payment 1' => [
             0 => ['fullName' => 'Patient C']
          ],
          'Payment 2' => [],
          'Payment 3' => [],
      ],
      'Room 3' => [
          'Payment 1' => [],
          'Payment 2' => [],
          'Payment 3' => [
             0 => ['fullName' => 'Patient E']
          ],
      ],
   ]
];
```

I've tried using loop this way:

```php
$mergedArray = [];

foreach ($rooms as $room) {
    $mergedArray[] = $room;
    foreach ($paymentMethods as $payment) {
        $mergedArray[$room] = $payment;
        foreach ($patients as $patient) {
            if ($patient->roomCode == $room->roomCode && $patient->paymentCode == $payment->paymentCode) {
                $mergedArray[$payment] = ['fullName' => $patient->fullName];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above code gave me `Illegal offset type` error. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: on which line?....

Comment: @nice_dev on this part of code: `$mergedArray[$payment] = ['fullName' => $patient->fullName];`

Comment: Why are you trying to implement a relational database in PHP? There are already several very well written tools available off the shelf for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code `$room` is an array, and there is an attempt to use it as a key (`$mergedArray[$room]`). That cannot work and is the reason for the error message you get.

It will be more efficient (and elegant) if you first key your room names and payment method names by their relevant codes in associative arrays:

```
$roomMap = array_column($rooms, "roomName", "roomCode");
$paymentMap = array_column($paymentMethods, "paymentName", "paymentCode");
```

Once you have that, you only need one loop:

```
foreach($patients as $patient) {
    $merged[$roomMap[$patient->roomCode]][$paymentMap[$patient->paymentCode]][]
                                           = ["fullName" => $patient->fullName];
}
```

Now `$merged` is:

```
[
  'Room 1' => [
    'Payment 1' => [
        ['fullName' => 'Patient A'],
        ['fullName' => 'Patient B'],
    ],
    'Payment 3' => [
        ['fullName' => 'Patient D'],
    ],
  ],
  'Room 2' => [
    'Payment 1' => [
        ['fullName' => 'Patient C'],
    ],
  ],
  'Room 3' => [
    'Payment 3' => [
        ['fullName' => 'Patient E'],
    ],
  ],
]
```

This way you don't get those empty payment slots in your result. If you really want those empty slots as well, then first initialise the targeted structure with empty arrays:

```
$merged = [];
foreach($roomMap as $roomName) {
    foreach($paymentMap as $paymentName) {
        $merged[$roomName][$paymentName] = [];
    }
}
foreach($patients as $patient) {
    $merged[$roomMap[$patient->roomCode]][$paymentMap[$patient->paymentCode]][] 
                                           = ["fullName" => $patient->fullName];
}
```

This will still be more efficient if the number of combinations of rooms and payments is less than the number of patients residing in the facility.

Comment: This line of code `foreach($patients as ["fullName" => $fullName, "roomCode" => $roomCode, "paymentCode" => $paymentCode]) {` gave me `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array` error

Comment: Which version of PHP do you have? It looks like your input for `$patients` is not an array of arrays, but array of objects? Can you check?

Comment: I have PHP version 7.4

Comment: That's fine. What about your `$patients` array, is it really a nested array, or an array of objects?

Comment: I think it's an array of objects. That array I get from CI query builder `result()`.

Comment: OK, but then your question does not represent it correctly.

Comment: OK, I updated my answer too.

Comment: @RizkyIrmawan, does it work for your case?

Comment: It still doesn't work. It gives me `Undefined index:` Maybe because `$rooms` and `$paymentMethods` are array of objects as well? I'll update my question

Comment: It doesn't matter if `$rooms` would be an array of objects, the same code will work. You can see it run [here](https://3v4l.org/FSjWf#v8.2.3). What surprises me though is that you give the impression that you don't know how the data is structured (*"Maybe"*...). It is of course essential to know what you have before you can write code to get something else from it. I will move on now.

Comment: Yes it is work, just gave me a random undefined index notice, but the data is exactly what I expected

Comment: Error messages come with a stack trace, a line number, ... so you can check *where* the error occurs, and which index is undefined. Then debug (i.e. set breakpoints, inspect variables there, ...).

Comment: The undefined index notice came from this line of code `$merged[$roomMap[$patient->roomCode]][$paymentMap[$patient->paymentCode]][] = ["fullName" => $patient->fullName];` but doesn't show the property that is undefined

Comment: But you can set a break point and [debug](https://www.php.net/manual/en/debugger-about.php), so you will know?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

Edit: solution corrected by adding if statement.

```php
$mergedArray = [];

foreach ($rooms as $room) {
    //create empty array for collecting payments
    $mergedArray[$room["roomName"]] = [];
    
    foreach ($paymentMethods as $payment) {
        //create empty array for filling it with patients later.
        $mergedArray[$room["roomName"]][$payment["paymentName"]] = [];
        
        foreach ($patients as $patient) {
            //push patients because key 'fullName' is duplicate
            //you cant add another key-value pair with the same key. 
            if ($patient["roomCode"] == $room["roomCode"] && $patient["paymentCode"] == $payment["paymentCode"]) {
                array_push(
                $mergedArray[$room["roomName"]][$payment["paymentName"]],
                ["fullName" => $patient["fullName"]]);
            }
            
        }
    }
}

print_r($mergedArray);
```